# Find the Max Value of each row

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Let's say
This is my table
| A | B | C |
|:--|:--|:--|
|123|342|130|
|562|988|234|
|245|890|234|

I want to create another column to find the maximum value of each row.
what function should I use and have to write it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out
Max_value = Max(max('FindMax'[M], 'FindMax'[V]), 'FindMax'[W])Max_value = Max(max('FindMax'[M], 'FindMax'[V]), 'FindMax'[W])